# Which order does find command use to print out

Tags: linux, find

What order does the `find` command use to print out a list of files?
Is this order different across different Linux distributions or versions?

Answer (score 2):

It uses [the order that the VFS gives them to it in](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13451/what-is-the-directory-order-of-files-in-a-directory-used-by-ls-u).

Comment: Will you please explain more? I am a totally newbie for VFS.

Comment: Did you read the question and answers I linked to?

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that there is a link. I just read and it's very helpful.