# I just deleted everything in my home directory. How? And why are some files still there?

Tags: bash, shell-script, zsh, rm, deleted-files

Never thought this would happen to me, but there you go. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

I ran a build script from a repository inside the wrong directory without looking at the source first. Here's the script `Scripts/BuildLocalWheelLinux.sh`:

```
cd ../Dependencies/cpython
mkdir debug
cd debug
../configure --with-pydebug --enable-shared
make
cd ../../..

cd ..
mkdir -p cmake-build-local
cd cmake-build-local
rm -rf *
cmake .. -DMVDIST_ONLY=True -DMVPY_VERSION=0 -DMVDPG_VERSION=local_build
make -j
cd ..

cd Distribution
python3 BuildPythonWheel.py ../cmake-build-local/[redacted]/core.so 0
python3 -m ensurepip
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
[more pip install stuff]
python3 -m setup bdist_wheel --plat-name manylinux1_x86_64 --dist-dir ../dist
cd ..
cd Scripts
```

The dangerous part seems to be

```
mkdir -p cmake-build-local
cd cmake-build-local
rm -rf *
```

But thinking about it, it actually seems like it couldn't possibly go wrong.

The way you're supposed to run this script is `cd Scripts; ./BuildLocalWheelLinux.sh`. When I ran it the first time, it showed an error on the very last line (as I learned afterwards). I was in a hurry, so I though "maybe the docs are outdated, I'll try running from the project root instead. So I ran `./Scripts/BuildLocalWheelLinux.sh`. Suddenly, vscodes theme and zoom level changed, my zsh terminal config was reset, terminal fonts were set to default, and I Ctrl+C'd once I realized what was happening.

There are some files remaining, but there's no obvious pattern to them:

```
$ ls -la
total 216
drwx------ 27 felix   felix   4096 May 12 18:08 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root    root    4096 Apr 15 16:39 ..
-rw-------  1 felix   felix  12752 Apr 19 11:07 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--  1 felix   felix   3980 Apr 15 13:40 .bashrc
drwxrwxrwx  7 felix   felix   4096 May 12 18:25 .cache
drwx------  8 felix   felix   4096 May 12 18:26 .config
drwx------  3 root    root    4096 Apr 13 21:40 .dbus
drwx------  2 felix   felix   4096 Apr 30 12:18 .docker
drwxr-xr-x  8 felix   felix   4096 Apr 15 13:40 .dotfiles
-rw-------  1 felix   felix   8980 Apr 13 18:10 examples.desktop
-rw-r--r--  1 felix   felix    196 Apr 19 15:19 .gitconfig
-rw-r--r--  1 felix   felix     55 Apr 16 13:56 .gitconfig.old
-rw-r--r--  1 felix   felix   1040 Apr 15 13:40 .gitmodules
drwx------  3 felix   felix   4096 May  6 10:10 .gnupg
-rw-r--r--  1 felix   felix   1848 May  5 14:24 heartbeat.tcl
-rw-------  1 felix   felix   1610 Apr 13 20:36 .ICEauthority
drwxr-xr-x  5 felix   felix   4096 Apr 21 16:39 .ipython
drwxr-xr-x  2 felix   felix   4096 May  4 09:35 .jupyter
-rw-------  1 felix   felix    161 Apr 27 14:23 .lesshst
drwx------  3 felix   felix   4096 May 12 18:08 .local
-rw-r--r--  1 felix   felix    140 Apr 29 17:54 minicom.log
drwx------  5 felix   felix   4096 Apr 13 18:25 .mozilla
drwxr-xr-x  2 felix   felix   4096 Apr 13 18:10 Music
drwxr-xr-x  6 felix   felix   4096 May 12 17:16 Nextcloud
-rw-r--r--  1 felix   felix     52 Apr 16 11:43 .nix-channels
-rw-------  1 felix   felix   1681 Apr 20 10:33 nohup.out
drwx------  3 felix   felix   4096 Apr 15 11:16 .pki
-rw-------  1 felix   felix    946 Apr 16 11:43 .profile
drwxr-xr-x  2 felix   felix   4096 Apr 13 18:10 Public
drwxr-xr-x  2 felix   felix   4096 May 12 18:08 .pylint.d
-rw-------  1 felix   felix   1984 May 12 18:06 .pythonhist
-rw-r--r--  1 felix   felix   2443 Apr 19 13:40 README.md
drwxr-xr-x 13 felix   felix   4096 May 12 18:08 repos
drwxr-xr-x  6 felix   felix   4096 Apr 19 11:08 snap
drwx------  3 felix   felix   4096 May  5 15:33 .ssh
drwxr-xr-x  5 felix   felix   4096 Apr 26 17:39 .stm32cubeide
drwxr-xr-x  5 felix   felix   4096 May  5 15:52 .stm32cubemx
drwxr-xr-x  2 felix   felix   4096 Apr 23 11:44 .stmcube
drwxr-xr-x  2 felix   felix   4096 Apr 13 18:10 Templates
drwxr-xr-x  3 felix   felix   4096 Apr 19 11:57 test
drwxr-xr-x  2 felix   felix   4096 Apr 13 18:10 Videos
-rw-------  1 felix   felix  14313 May 12 10:45 .viminfo
-rw-r--r--  1 felix   felix    816 Apr 15 13:40 .vimrc
drwxr-xr-x  3 felix   felix   4096 Apr 16 12:08 .vscode
-rw-r--r--  1 felix   felix   2321 Apr 19 18:47 weird_bug.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 felix   felix    162 Apr 15 13:40 .xprofile
```

`.config` is gone, as well as some standard XDG dirs like Pictures and Desktop, but .bashrc is still there. `.nix-channels` is still there, but `.nix-defexpr` was nuked.

So, this leads me to two questions:

1. **What went wrong?** I'd like to fix this build script and make a PR to prevent this from happening in the future.
2. **What order were the files deleted in?** Obviously not in alphabetical order, but `*` expands in alphabetical order, so something else is going on here, it seems.

Comment: As for your second question. `rm` would use the `directory order`. More details here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13451 . It would be like the default ordering of `find`'s output.

Comment: If the `mkdir` fails and the directory didn't already exist, the `cd` will fail, and it's game over.

Comment: Just a comment: it's way better to do `cd ..; rm -rf thedirectoryiknowshouldbenamedthisway` than `rm -rf *` (which fails to remove dot files anyway).

Comment: As a best practice, this shell scripts should stop executing as soon as the first error occurs, which probably would have been at the very first line `cd ../Dependencies/cpython`. That can be done by putting a `&&` at the end of every command. There is more to it because sometimes it's ok for a command to fail, but that can be handled as well.

Comment: @mars I think `set -e` at the beginning is a more effective way of doing this.

Comment: `set -e` has [its own issues](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105). `cd foo || exit 1` is more explicit with fewer surprises.

Comment: @chepner Oh nice, that's an interesting article. Maybe I'll just start writing my build-scripts in python :D

Comment: @chepner What about `cd cmake-build-local && rm -rf *`?

Comment: That would prevent the wrong files from being deleted, but allows the script to continue. That may or may not be the right thing to do.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Ouch. [You aren't the first victim](https://github.com/hoffstadt/DearPyGui/issues/796).

#### What went wrong?

Starting in your home directory, e.g. `/home/felix`, or even in `/home/felix/src` or `/home/felix/Downloads/src`.

> ```
> cd ../Dependencies/cpython
> ```

Failed because there is no `../Dependencies`.

> ```
> mkdir debug
> cd debug
> ```

You're now in the subdirectory `debug` of the directory you started from.

> ```
> ../configure --with-pydebug --enable-shared
> make
> ```

Does nothing because there's no `../configure` or `make`.

> ```
> cd ../../..
> cd ..
> ```

If you started out no more than three directory levels deep, with `cd debug` reaching a fourth level, the current directory is now the root directory. If you started out four directory levels deep the current directory is now `/home`.

> ```
> mkdir -p cmake-build-local
> ```

This fails since you don't have permission to write in `/` or `/home`.

> ```
> cd cmake-build-local
> ```

This fails since there is no directory `cmake-build-local`.

We now get to…

#### What order were the files deleted in?

> ```
> rm -rf *
> ```

This tries to recursively delete every file in the current directory, which is `/` or `/home`. The home directories are enumerated in alphabetical order, but the files underneath are enumerated in the arbitrary order of directory traversal. It's the same order as `ls --sort=none` (unless `rm` decides to use a different order for some reason). Note that this order is generally not preserved in backups, and can change when a file is created or removed in the directory.

#### How to fix the script

First, almost any shell script should have `set -e` near the top. `set -e` causes the script to abort if a command fails. (A command fails if its exit status is nonzero.) `set -e` is not a panacea, because there are circumstances where it doesn't go into effect. But it's the bare minimum you can expect and it would have done the right thing here.

(Also the script should start with a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) line to indicate which shell to use, e.g. `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/bin/bash`. But that wouldn't help with this problem.)

`rm -rf *`, or variants like `rm -rf $foo.*` (what if `$foo` turns out to be empty?), are fragile. Here, instead of

```
mkdir -p cmake-build-local
cd cmake-build-local
rm -rf *
```

it would be more robust to just remove and re-create the directory. (This would not preserve the permissions on the directory, but here this is not a concern.)

```
rm -rf cmake-build-local
mkdir cmake-build-local
cd cmake-build-local
```

Another way is more robust against deleting the wrong files, but more fragile against missing files to delete: delete only files that are known to have been built, by running `make clean` which has `rm` commands for known build targets and for known extensions (e.g. `rm *.o` is ok).

Comment: Perfect answer! I already submitted a PR.

Comment: And the PR got approved and merged about 5 hours later. Gotta love open source.

Comment: `set -eo pipefail` fixes most of the shortcomings of `set -e`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I wouldn't say that. It fixes one of the major shortcomings, but not the biggest one, which is that anything inside a conditional is untouched by `set -e`, even if it doesn't contribute to the result of the conditional. `if some_function; then …` completely ignores errors in `some_function`.

Comment: @Gilles Fair, though arguably (depending on the use-case) a failure in the function isn’t *ignored*, it does the right thing (namely make the conditional false). Having “proper” error handling would of course be better. Still, `-o pipefail` is arguably what `set -e` should do *anyway* (and what everybody would intuitively expect it to do), and I can’t think of a reason not to always use it.

Comment: @KonradRudolph No, a failure in the function _is_ ignored! It doesn't make the conditional false. Here's a simple case without a function `sh -c 'set -e; if false; true; then echo oops; fi`' (in the real world, the failing command usually buried in a function, which makes it hard to find.). As for `pipefail`, the reason not to use it is that not all shells have it.

Comment: @Gilles Jeez, that’s terrible! And why didn’t I know that?! I was sure I had used this behaviour previously. Thanks, now I’ll be spending my Friday double-checking various build pipelines. (Regarding not all shells supporting this: yes, that’s true, and that’s IMHO a very strong reason to use Bash for distributable shell scripts; plain Bourne Shell has too many foot-guns. Bash still has many (as shown here) but *substantially* fewer.)

Comment: @iFreilicht "gotta love open source". Except when a botched script deletes your home folder.

Comment: @EricDuminil the point is I don't have to wait months for a fix. But yeah, if I didn't try to do it myself, this wouldn't have happened.

Answer (score 11):

Tracing your `cd` calls, assuming we are running the script in `~/Distribution/Scripts` and assuming that every `cd` succeeds:

```
cd ../Dependencies/cpython
```

We are now in `~/Distribution/Dependencies/cpython`.

```
mkdir debug
cd debug
```

We are now in `~/Distribution/Dependencies/cpython/debug`.

```
cd ../../..
```

We are now in `~/Distribution`.

```
cd ..
```

We are now in your home directory.

```
mkdir -p cmake-build-local
cd cmake-build-local
```

We are now in `~/cmake-build-local`.  This is where you run `rm -rf *`.

```
cd ..
```

We are now back in your home directory

```
cd Distribution
```

We are now in `~/Distribution`.

```
cd ..
cd Scripts
```

We are now in `~/Scripts` (you get an error from this because you are one level further up than what you expect).

---

Now then.  You tried running the same script, but from `~/Distribution`.

```
cd ../Dependencies/cpython
```

This fails. This leaves you still in `~/Distribution`.

```
mkdir debug
cd debug
```

You are now in `~/Distribution/debug`.

```
cd ../../..
```

You are now in `~/..` (probably in `/home`).

```
cd ..
```

You are most likely in `/` now.

```
cd Distribution
mkdir -p cmake-build-local
cd cmake-build-local
```

These probably fail due to "no such file or directory" and "permission denied".

```
rm -rf *
```

You are still in the `/` directory, and your `rm` command would try to delete every single file in the whole filesystem.  Permissions only allows for deleting files that are located in directories that you have write permissions to, so you likely only loose files in `/tmp` and in your home directory.

The arguments listed on the command line of `rm` would have been processed the order that `*` expanded them (lexicographical, i.e., `bin`, `boot`, `cdrom`, `dev`, `etc`, etc.)  Each directory listed would then have been processed recursively, and in "directory order" (unsorted).

---

What you should have done:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

topdir=$HOME/Distribution

mkdir -p "$topdir/Dependencies/cpython/debug"
(
    cd "$topdir/Dependencies/cpython/debug" || exit 1

    ../configure --with-pydebug --enable-shared
    make
)

rm -rf "$topdir/cmake-build-local"
mkdir -p "$topdir/cmake-build-local"
(
    cd "$topdir/cmake-build-local" || exit 1

    cmake .. -DMVDIST_ONLY=True -DMVPY_VERSION=0 -DMVDPG_VERSION=local_build
    make -j
)

(
    cd "$topdir" || exit 1

    python3 BuildPythonWheel.py ../cmake-build-local/[redacted]/core.so 0
    python3 -m ensurepip
    python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
    python3 -m setup bdist_wheel --plat-name manylinux1_x86_64 --dist-dir ../dist
)
```

The working directory within each separate `( ... )` sub-shell is local to that sub-shell. The initial `cd` in a sub-shell will not affect the working directory of the "outer" environment.  The rest of the code uses absolute pathnames that do not depend on the initial working directory of the user's shell session.  Note particularly that the `rm` command does not blindly expand `*` but rather deletes a specific directory specified via an absolute path (this would not go horribly wrong if the directory does not exist).

Comment: Subshells seem like a much more robust solution, thanks!

Comment: Ah, and `cmake-build-local` is located in the project root folder

Answer (score 5):

If the script assumes that it is run from inside `Scripts`, then none of these will do what the script author intended:

```
cd ../Dependencies/cpython
mkdir debug
cd debug
cd ../../..
cd ..
mkdir -p cmake-build-local
cd cmake-build-local
```

The first `cd` will fail, the second `cd` moves into a folder, then the  `cd ../../..` and `cd ..` probably put you somewhere above your home directory (maybe in the `/home` directory, where you usually don't have rights to make anything, so the `mkdir` and subsequent `cd` fails). Then the `*` probably expanded to your home directory, so `rm -rf` operated on it, recursing into the contents, which would explain the random order of deletes (directory entries aren't sorted in any particular order).